# How to convert char string to one single int number if the string also contains letters

Tags: c, string, char, int

I have a very basic question, if I have a string of chars like this: `char charv1[6] = "v445"` or `v666` How can I get the numbers and turn them into a single integer with value: `445` or `666`?

I have been trying this code but something goes wrong ...:

```
            size = (strlen(charv1)-1);
            for(aux = size; aux > 0; aux--){
                if(aux == (size)){
                    v1 = charv1[aux]-'0';
                }
                else{

                    aux2 = (charv1[aux]-'0')*10;
                    printf("%d\n", aux2);
                    v1 = v1 + aux2;
                }
            }
```

`charv1` contains the string: `v445`etc

I remember a few years ago, I did it recursively but I do not remember how, but now I do not need an elegant solution ... I need one that just works.

Comment: Is the first character of that string a letter followed by digits?

Comment: @EdHeal    Yes, always the character `'v'` followed by digits (assuming the role of char).

Examples: `v1`, `v33556`, `v23` ...etc and I have to store those numbers in a variable of type `int` like: `int i = 33556` or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a function called `strtol()` , and it's used like this :

```
 long dest = 0;
    char source[10] = "122";

    dest = strtol(source , NULL , 10); // arg 1 : the string to be converted arg2 : allways NULL arg3 : the base (16 for hex , 10 for decimal , 2 for binary ...)
```

but in your case you should replace this `dest = strtol(source , NULL , 10);` with this `dest = strtol((source + 1) , NULL , 10)` or `dest = strtol(&source[1] , NULL , 10);`to ignore the first character because `strtol` stops at the first non-digit character it encounters

Answer (score 2):

just use `strtol`,

```
long int num;
char* end;
num = strtol(&charv1[1], &end, 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about sscanf

```
sscanf( charv1, "%*c%d", &i); //skip the first char then read an integer
```

http://codepad.org/vOg22G8e

Answer (score 1):

Then

```
   int x = atoi(&charv1[1]);
   printf("Here it is as an integer %d\n", x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to multiply 10 every loop. This works:

```
        size = (strlen(charv1)-1);
        dec=10;
        for(aux = size; aux > 0; aux--){
            if(aux == (size)){
                v1 = charv1[aux]-'0';
            }
            else{

                aux2 = (charv1[aux]-'0')*dec;
                printf("%d\n", aux2);
                v1 = v1 + aux2;
                dec*=10;
            }
        }
```